# Recovering folders in executable drive converted into 0 byte "Unix Executable" files

Tags: macos, external-disk, data-recovery

I had an, MS-DOS formatted external flash drive connected to my MacBook. It had bent a few files at the next. Most probably because of this, when I accidentally brushed my finger against it, it disconnected from my laptop. I got the "disk not ejected properly" notification from macOS.

I inserted the drive back in and tried opening the folders I was working in – and to my horror, it seems as though all the folders had been converted into 0 byte "Unix Executable" files.

- No files in the root of the drive were affected – only the folders in the root of the drive had been 'converted' into this strange 'file'
- The folder modified/created dates seem to have been retained, except the folder is not a folder anymore
- `cd /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE/myFolder` returns the message `Not a directory`
- `file /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE/myFolder` returns the message `empty`
- Duplicating one of these mystery files seems to happen instantaneously, implying that the 'folders' contain no information
- The drive seems to have a suspiciously large amount of space free

Trying to open one of these files opens a terminal window which outputs the following:

```
user$ /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE/myFolder ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Trying to open the 'file' with Sublime Text shows exactly what you would expect from a 0 byte file – absolutely nothing.

Thankfully I have a relatively recent backup of this drive. However, I am horrified that this happened in the first place.

Is it possible that disconnecting the external drive accidentally caused the folders to become corrupted? Is there any way to recover this data, or is it gone for good?

### Appendix

```
for i in /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE; do diskutil list "$i"; diskutil info "$i"; df -Hg "$i";done
```

Below is the output from the above command.

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 GB     disk4
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 EXTERNAL_DRIVE               2.0 GB     disk4s1
   Device Identifier:        disk4s1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk4s1
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk4

   Volume Name:              EXTERNAL_DRIVE
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE

   Partition Type:           DOS_FAT_32
   File System Personality:  MS-DOS FAT32
   Type (Bundle):            msdos
   Name (User Visible):      MS-DOS (FAT32)

   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              1C03C1DE-7B50-3127-8D83-6E40C62142BC

   Disk Size:                2.0 GB (2003795968 Bytes) (exactly 3913664 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       2.0 GB (1999863808 Bytes) (exactly 3905984 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:        27.8 MB (27750400 Bytes) (exactly 54200 512-Byte-Units) (1.4%)
   Volume Available Space:   2.0 GB (1972113408 Bytes) (exactly 3851784 512-Byte-Units) (98.6%)
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Removable
   Media Removal:            Software-Activated


Filesystem   1G-blocks Used Available Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk4s1         1    0         1     2%       0     0  100%   /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE
```

Comment: Update the Q with the output of the following command. Just copy and paste the command into your terminal. It's not destructive, just gathers relevant information concerning the drive. `for i in /Volumes/EXTERNAL_DRIVE; do diskutil list "$i"; diskutil info "$i"; df -Hg "$i";done`

Comment: Thank you for the command. I would prefer to link to the output, which is over [here.](https://ghostbin.com/paste/5pwpu)